# How to customize Scanner frame for android ZBar QrCode?

Tags: android, layout, size, zbar

I am using this library,https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner

How do i customize the size of the Scanner frame?

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    if(!isCameraAvailable()) {
        // Cancel request if there is no rear-facing camera.
        cancelRequest();
        return;
    }

    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

    // Create and configure the ImageScanner;
    setupScanner();

    // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
    // and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
    setContentView(mPreview);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap everything up in a FrameLayout:

```
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);

    //Create a FrameLyout to hold some views
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

    //Example of a toolbar view to add
    Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_general, layout, false);

    layout.addView(mPreview);//Add your CameraPreview
    layout.addView(bar);//<----Add the example toolbar
    //layout.addView(imageOverlay1);//<----This is where you'll add more views
    //layout.addView(imageOverlay2);
    setContentView(layout);
```

Hope this helps.